# Php PDO mySQL - suitability for major expansion

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Currently redeveloping booking systems for upcoming tour operator. Based on the booking procedures, payment and product guidelines the number of rows could exceed 10 million in 3 years with bookings referencing a product manifest that would be queried WHERE booking lDs match.

What considerations should be taken into account now to ensure fast query response of PDO prepared statements, in particular when performing JOINS to multiple tables in queries based on a single unified referencing ID.

Any detail you can provide would be extremely helpful.

Comment: 10 mil records is not much for a relational database. Just index columns you select and join on, and you should be fine.

Comment: If one query were to reference a record in one table on ID with say 100,000 records referencing a 10 products by ID from a product manifest of say 10,000 records each referencing a booking stamp from a table growing by 1000 rows a day all on correlating ID. What would you estimate the response time to be. Anything more than 5 secs and we'd have a problem of usability for each user. I know that that is an inexact science but if you were to theorise, is that the right approach or should we consider something else.

Comment: This is exactly the realm of use for relational databases. Your numbers don't seem to be a cause of concern, you should be able to optimize such a query to well under a second. Direct references (e.g. foreign keys and comparison against constants) are _very_ optimized by indexing alone.